# How do I merge duplicated contacts?

Tags: duplicate-contacts

I am having problems with merging contacts.  Some contacts have merged but others have not.

Comment: Sarah - welcome to SE. That's far too general a question for anyone to answer here. Have you looked at the documentation at https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/common-workflows/deduping-and-merging/ . There are quite a lot of options for the matching rules and you often have to try a few options to catch exactly what you want. If after that you still have problems then ask a specific question here.

Comment: The other thing to consider is 'prevention' eg checking that your forms are set up with good usage of 'matching rules' to reduce the creation of duplicates (ditto for doing imports)

Comment: Also there are issues with merging contacts where Cases are involved due to the relationships that Cases require - just dealing with this for a client currently so is 'top of the head' in terms of why merging might fail.

Comment: Welcome!  Please edit your question and describe what you did.  Did you get any messages?  Are you using the 'Batch Merge' option? Screenshots might help so long as you avoid showing any personal data.